# Convert and Object Class to IComparable in c#

Tags: c#, icomparable

I am implementing a binary tree using the following code:

```
class Binary<T>:Binary
   where T: IComparable

{
```

But I'm also looking to use class objects in the tree:

```
Binary Bin = null;
Bin = new Binary<Product>();
```

This obviously doesnt work because `Product` is not `IComparable`. I tried doing this to make it work:

```
 public class Product: IComparable<Product>
    {
        public int Id = 0;

        public int CompareTo(Product p)
        {
            if (p==null)
            {
                return 1;  
            }
            if (p!=null)
            {
                return this.Id.CompareTo(p.Id);
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

`Id` is the value of `Product` intended to be used in all comparisons. But this doesn't work and I dont know what else to do. Is it possible to do what i want? Or is there another way I can use the class `Product` as an `IComparable`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hint: `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` are separate interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Your class `Product` implements generic [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx), where your generic class `Binary<T>` expects generic type that implements non-generic [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Update `Binary<T>` declaration to use[`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) in the constraint:

```
class Binary<T>:Binary
   where T: IComparable<T>
{
```

Comment: Boo. I just got ninja'd.